# Is it possible to reduce the number of match arms caused by generics?

Tags: rust

I am "serializing" and "deserializing" a generic struct to and from an SQLite database. The struct has two members whose values are of generic types, `V` and `T`, both constrained to the `DataType` trait. When I want to reconstruct these from the information in the database, I haven't been able to find a way around specifying match arms for every combination of `V` and `T`. Given that I will eventually have around 20 data types, that means 20 * 20 = 400 match arms. Is there any way around this? An unsafe solution is also acceptable.

Here is a MWE with two data types:

```rust
// A somewhat boilerplaty, but working solution to 
// store and retrieve a generically typed struct
// in a SQLite database.
use rusqlite::{params, Connection, Statement};
use rusqlite::types::{ToSql, FromSql, ValueRef};

// This trait needs to be implemented for every type 
// the GenericStruct will hold as a value.
trait DataType : ToSql + FromSql {
    type TargetType;
    fn convert(value: &ValueRef) -> Self::TargetType;
    fn data_type(&self) -> &'static str;
}

impl DataType for String { 
    type TargetType = String;
    fn data_type(&self) -> &'static str {
        "String"
    }
    fn convert(value: &ValueRef) -> Self::TargetType {
        String::from(value.as_str().unwrap())
    }
} 
impl DataType for usize { 
    type TargetType = usize;
    fn data_type(&self) -> &'static str {
        "usize"
    }
    fn convert(value: &ValueRef) -> Self::TargetType {
        usize::try_from(value.as_i64().unwrap()).unwrap()
    }
} 

// This is the generic struct that is persisted in SQLite.
#[derive(Debug)]
struct GenericStruct<V: DataType, T: DataType> {
    value: V,
    time: T
}

// This is just to keep the database stuff together.
struct Database<'db> {
    pub add_struct: Statement<'db>,
    pub get_struct: Statement<'db>
}
impl<'db> Database<'db> {
    pub fn new<'con>(connection: &'con Connection) -> Database<'con> {
        // the table will hold both the value and its Rust type
        connection.execute_batch("
            create table if not exists GenericStruct (
                value any not null, 
                value_type text not null, 
                time any not null,
                time_type text not null
            )
        ").unwrap();
        Database {
            add_struct: connection.prepare("
                insert into GenericStruct 
                    (value, value_type, time, time_type) 
                values 
                    (?, ?, ?, ?)
            ").unwrap(),
            get_struct: connection.prepare("
                select 
                    value, value_type, time, time_type 
                from GenericStruct
            ").unwrap()
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let sqlite = Connection::open("generic.db").unwrap();
    let mut database = Database::new(&sqlite);
    let g1 = GenericStruct {
        value: String::from("Hello World"), 
        time: 20090921
    };
    let g2 = GenericStruct {
        value: 42, 
        time: String::from("now")
    };
    // Add the two structs to the sqlite database
    database.add_struct.execute(
        params![&g1.value, &g1.value.data_type(), &g1.time, &g1.time.data_type()]
    ).unwrap();
    database.add_struct.execute(
        params![&g2.value, &g2.value.data_type(), &g2.time, &g2.time.data_type()]
    ).unwrap();
    // Now there are two different types in the database.
    // Retrieve the two structs again.
    let mut rows = database.get_struct.query([]).unwrap();
    while let Some(row) = rows.next().unwrap() {
        let data_type = row.get_unwrap::<_, String>(1);
        let time_type = row.get_unwrap::<_, String>(3);
        // I want to lookup the converter instead 
        // of explicitly listing alternatives...
        match (data_type.as_str(), time_type.as_str()) {
            ("String", "usize") => { 
                println!("{:?}", GenericStruct {
                    value: String::convert(&row.get_ref_unwrap(0)), 
                    time: usize::convert(&row.get_ref_unwrap(2))
                });
            },
            ("usize", "String") => {
                println!("{:?}", GenericStruct {
                    value: usize::convert(&row.get_ref_unwrap(0)), 
                    time: String::convert(&row.get_ref_unwrap(2))
                });
            }, 
            _ => ()
        }
    }    
}
```

I have also set it up in a playground here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7bb2403d88c3318348ba50d90763c225

Comment: Have you considered a macro?

Comment: I tried writing a regular macro that would work on a combination of inputs, but could not get it to work. It was my first attempt at writing a macro though, so maybe it's possible? I did not try procedural macros.

Comment: You should be able to work out something with`macro_rules`.  something like `data_types!(Type1, Type2, Type3)`. Checkout https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros/dry.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the following (pretty complex) macro.

```rust
macro_rules! generate_match {
    // First, we generate a table of permutations.
    // Suppose we have the tuple (String, usize, ()).
    // The table we generate will be the following:
    // [
    //     [ String, usize,  ()     ]
    //     [ usize,  (),     String ]
    //     [ (),     String, usize  ]
    // ]

    // Empty case
    { @generate_permutations_table
        $row:ident
        match ($e:expr)
        table = [ $($table:tt)* ]
        rest = [ ]
        transformed = [ $($transformed:ty,)* ]
    } => {
        generate_match! { @permutate_entry
            $row
            match ($e) { }
            table = [ $($table)* ]
        }
    };
    { @generate_permutations_table
        $row:ident
        match ($e:expr)
        table = [ $($table:tt)* ]
        rest = [ $current:ty, $($rest:ty,)* ]
        transformed = [ $($transformed:ty,)* ]
    } => {
        generate_match! { @generate_permutations_table
            $row
            match ($e)
            table = [
                $($table)*
                [ $current, $($rest,)* $($transformed,)* ]
            ]
            rest = [ $($rest,)* ]
            transformed = [ $($transformed,)* $current, ]
        }
    };

    // For each entry in the table, we generate all combinations of the first type with the others.
    // For example, for the entry [ String, usize, () ] we'll generate the following permutations:
    // [
    //     (String, usize)
    //     (String, ())
    // ]

    // Empty case
    { @permutate_entry
        $row:ident
        match ($e:expr) { $($match_tt:tt)* }
        table = [ ]
    } => {
        match $e {
            $($match_tt)*
            _ => {}
        }
    };
    { @permutate_entry
        $row:ident
        match ($e:expr) { $($match_tt:tt)* }
        table = [
            [ $current:ty, $($others:ty,)* ]
            $($table:tt)*
        ]
    } => {
        generate_match! { @generate_arm
            $row
            match ($e) { $($match_tt)* }
            table = [ $($table)* ]
            current = [ $current ]
            others = [ $($others,)* ]
        }
    };

    // Finally, We generate `match` arms from each pair.
    // For example, for the pair (String, usize):
    //     ("String", "usize") => {
    //         let value = GenericStruct {
    //             value: <String as DataType>::convert(&row.get_ref_unwrap(0)),
    //             time: <usize as DataType>::convert(&row.get_ref_unwrap(2)),
    //         };
    //         // Process `value...`
    //     }

    // Empty case: permutate the next table entry.
    { @generate_arm
        $row:ident
        match ($e:expr) { $($match_tt:tt)* }
        table = [ $($table:tt)* ]
        current = [ $current:ty ]
        others = [ ]
    } => {
        generate_match! { @permutate_entry
            $row
            match ($e) { $($match_tt)* }
            table = [ $($table)* ]
        }
    };
    { @generate_arm
        $row:ident
        match ($e:expr) { $($match_tt:tt)* }
        table = [ $($table:tt)* ]
        current = [ $current:ty ]
        others = [ $first_other:ty, $($others:ty,)* ]
    } => {
        generate_match! { @generate_arm
            $row
            match ($e) {
                $($match_tt)*
                (stringify!($current), stringify!($first_other)) => {
                    let value = GenericStruct {
                        value: <$current as DataType>::convert(&$row.get_ref_unwrap(0)),
                        time: <$first_other as DataType>::convert(&$row.get_ref_unwrap(2)),
                    };
                    // Here you actually do whatever you want with the value. Adjust for your needs.
                    println!("{:?}", value);
                }
            }
            table = [ $($table)* ]
            current = [ $current ]
            others = [ $($others,)* ]
        }
    };

    // Entry
    (
        match ($e:expr) from ($($ty:ty),+) in $row:ident
    ) => {
        generate_match! { @generate_permutations_table
            $row
            match ($e)
            table = [ ]
            rest = [ $($ty,)+ ]
            transformed = [ ]
        }
    };
}
```

Invoke with:

```rust
generate_match!(
    match ((data_type.as_str(), time_type.as_str()))
        from (String, usize /* more types... */)
        in row
);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f0395a58ea5c58e6f3140565b08b15d1).

Comment: Thank you very much, and let me just say that is quite far from my first attempt at macros. I found it quite difficult to find resources on how to write anything beyond very simple macros. May I ask where you learnt how to do that?

Comment: [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/index.html) is an excellent resource.

Comment: But this is something you need to gain experience in. I like complex macros, and thus, many times, even where there is a no-macro solution (which I prefer), I still write the macro just for fun. That helps me in case like this one ;)

Comment: But be prepared to _hard_ work. Debugging macros is a chore.

Comment: Not saying that complex macros are good - most of the times, they ain't.